# Error Importing a Symfony project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, symfony

I'm trying to use Eclipse to work with Symfony2.
I'm used to Eclipse in Java but not really with PHP.

When I try to import a project with import wizard, everything is fine until the very few last moments, when I get this error :
[image: Eclipse message]

As you can see, The error log panel is empty, and there is even no log file in my brand new workspace. (but it would appear if I get another error elsewhere)

Not my goal but it could provide some infos :
If I create a new Eclipse Symfony2 project from scrap, I get a fully working dummy website. Still, there remain 2 "redcross" errors:

- cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'configurator' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.    (in /app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml  line 2106)  XML Problem
  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'factory'. One of '{"http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":file, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":argument, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":configurator, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":call, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":tag, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":property}' is expected.  appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml /rezdfezrdfrezdfr/app/cache/dev line 1265   XML Problem
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'factory'. One of '{"http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":file, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":argument, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":configurator, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":call, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":tag, "http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":property}' is expected.
  (in /app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml  line 1265)

Since it is not my goal right now, I'm didn't debug these errors yet, but I plan to. EDIT : as I saw on several SO posts, I disabled my project validators to ignore XML validation. No effect :-(

I think it is not the same as [Error Importing a Symfony project in Eclipse with dubture plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861206/error-importing-a-symfony-project-in-eclipse-with-dubture-plugin), since I dont get any log.

Do anybody know this problem and have a way to have the import wizard working ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not a direct answer but i am using Netbeans and i like it very much. Did you ever try? Its free: https://netbeans.org/

Comment: @Frankbeen Yes, not really an answer, but still a great advice ! I would rather use Eclipse because I know it well, but I could do what I wanted with netbeans, so thank you very much !